# SonarQube 5.2 issues refresh on dashboard

Tags: sonarqube, sonarqube5.2

Did I miss something ?

On the dashboad, I can see see all issues. I click on any link in the widget and jump to the issues list.
I made some changes in my code and set issues as "Resolve as fixed".
[image]

But when I go back to the dashboad, the widget still display old counter.
[image]

May be I have to wait a little, to get a cache updated or something like this ?

Regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figures that you get on dashboards are based on the latest analysis - because they are precomputed for efficiency of all search requests. This is mentioned on the tooltip that you will see if you put your mouse over the figures:

[image]

On the contrary, the "Issues" page shows dynamic content. So indeed, when you update some issues on that page, your changes will be reflected on your dashboards after the next analysis.